# Is there "\n" equivalent in VBscript?

Tags: string, vbscript

I want to use the `Replace` function in VBScript to replace all line breaks in a string for `"\n"`. I come from Java, so using `\n` inside a string means a line break.

Is there an equivalent in VBScript?

Comment: I know in vb its vbcrlf.

Comment: @David actually prefer to use `vbNewLine` which isn’t environment specific (will match `vbCr`, `vbLf` and `vbCrLf`).

Comment: Replace of "\n" like in Java strings you have to use vbLf as equivalent, "\r" is then vbCr and "\r\n" is vbCrLf.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For replace you can use `vbCrLf`:

```
Replace(string, vbCrLf, "")
```

You can also use `chr(13)+chr(10)`.

I seem to remember in some odd cases that `chr(10)` comes before `chr(13)`.

Comment: I remember that some line breaks where only `chr(13)`, some only `chr(10)`, and some `VbCrLf`.

Comment: I appreciate the 2nd meanings in your example (Replace the STRING of VB's STUPID CR/LF's with empty string `""`)

Comment: @ZoharPeled in which case use `vbNewLine` instead to cover both scenarios.

Answer (score 16):

[This page](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/dada61a7-ec5f-4686-8ccf-f3a293b281c8.asp) has a table of string constants including `vbCrLf`

> `vbCrLf` | Chr(13) & Chr(10) | Carriage return–linefeed combination

Answer (score 10):

As David and Remou pointed out, `vbCrLf` if you want a carriage-return-linefeed combination. Otherwise, `Chr(13)` and `Chr(10)` (although some VB-derivatives have `vbCr` and `vbLf`; VBScript may well have those, worth checking before using `Chr`).

Answer (score 6):

Tried and tested. I know that this works:

```
Replace(EmailText, vbNewLine, "<br>")
```

i.e. `vbNewLine` is also the equivalent of `\n`

Answer (score 4):

I think it's `vbcrlf`.

```
replace(s, vbcrlf, "<br />")
```

Comment: Note that self-closing tags like `<br />` are only meaningful in XHTML. Use `<br>` in HTML:
https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/self-closing-tags-are-mostly-meaningless-in-html/

Answer (score 4):

I had to use vbLf only in an ASP script where the original data was POSTed from a PHP script on a cPanel box over to ASP on a win server

(VBScript)

```
EmailText = Replace(EmailText, vbLf, "<br>")
```