# How to split random scanned text into two different lines

Tags: vb.net

I am pretty new to VB. I have a text box where I scan randow barcodes into a text box which contain letters and numbers how do I split this so that it reads as two separate lines in the same text box
ex: this how it looks when its first scanned
ZM123456789123
I want it to look like this
M123456
789123
I was able to remove the letter Z which means nothing but I am stuck separating the text

```
Private Sub TextBox29_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox29.TextChanged
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox29.Text) = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'ZM123456I1234
    TextBox29.Text = TextBox29.Text.ToUpper.Replace("Z", Nothing)
```

Comment: do you want separate lines - or just a space adding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203710/is-there-n-equivalent-in-vbscript

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
TextBox29.Text = TextBox29.Text.Substring(1).Insert(7, " ")
```

The `substring` strips off the first character, the `insert` adds a space at the 7th (zero based) character position.